# Cron Function on AWS Lambda by Serverless runs on alpha stage instaed of prod?

Tags: deployment, aws-lambda, cron, yaml, serverless

I already try with serverless.yml file by writing custom & it's active for prod only,but It's running on prod as well as alpha.

custom field is as below:

```
custom:
  defaultStage: dev

  enabled:
    alpha: false
    dev: false
    prod: true
```

cron function is as below:

```
 sendData:
    handler: sendData.handler
    enabled: ${self:custom.enabled.${self:provider.stage}}
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(30 1 ? * MON *)
          description: 'Runs every Monday at 7:00 AM'
```

These two stages from different account, When I was trying deploying on prod it's run properly but in case of stage alpha deployment it's remain active for alpha, which I already set as false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the `enabled` flag on the function, however it should be on the `schedule` event:

```
 sendData:
    handler: sendData.handler
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(30 1 ? * MON *)
          enabled: ${self:custom.enabled.${self:provider.stage}}
          description: 'Runs every Monday at 7:00 AM'
```